# How do I get GCC to work?

Tags: c, gcc

I am using Vim as my editor and GCC as my compiler, but it’s not working quite right. Let‘s say I am making a basic program to determine if a number is odd or even. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &i);

    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    { 
        printf("Your number is even.\n");
    }
    else if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf("Your number is odd.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I am programming this wrong, or gcc is just not a good compiler, or whatever. I am running linux, which I dual boot with windows. Now I press ctrl-d to stop the process, and only then does it print me back my number, and tell if it is odd or even. It isn't just this one, a lot of other programs with similar formats seem to do this to.

```
~ $ ./test
Enter a number: 45 
45                         //I press enter, nothing happends. Ctrl-d 
Your number is even.       //ctrl-d again
~ $
```

So what I'm asking is, is there a way to program it so that I don't have to quit the program in order for it to work, or is there another compiler that wouldn't have this problem? I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted with Windows 8.1.

Comment: remove the `getchar()` in th end and check once. BTW, why did you add that?

Comment: I'm reading a book called learn C the hard way. Not really sure what I am doing haha.

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @Haris It may be for preventing terminal windows from vanishing soon after printing the result and then the program ends when it is launched from an IDE. Unfornately, I don't think it is effective because there will be some character which was't read by `scanf` in the `stdin`, then the `getchar();` will read the character and will return immediately.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Always enable all warnings when compiling (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  Then fix the warnings.  in this case, two warnings from unused parameters `argc` and `argv[]`  to fix, declare main as: `int main( void )`   Also, the declaration of main() is incorrect because the second parameter (if any parameters) is either `char * argv[]` or `char ** argv`    Before posting code, actually compile it and fix the problems the compiler finds

Comment: to make a program pause, using getchar() do the following: `while( getchar() != EOF);   getchar();`  which will clean out the input stream `stdin` then wait for the user to enter any keystroke

Comment: You should read the documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and use the result item count: `if (scanf("%d",&i)==1)`. You'll better initialize all your variables: `int i=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` in the format for `scanf` means "read until hit into non-whitespace character and then ignore them". Remove it and make the format for reading `"%d"`.

Answer (score 1):

to get `gcc` to work from vim,

goto the vim command prompt

```
shell gcc <and all needed parameters>
```

Or open another command window

set it to the same directory as the program being edited

```
gcc <and all needed parameters>
```

in general, try to make the compile step separate from the link step. I.E. to compile:

```
gcc -c <mySource.c> -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o mySource.o
```

if any header files, other than those in the default 'include' path then add

```
-I<pathToHeaderFile>
```

which is often in the same directory so would be:

```
-I.
```

then link with:

```
gcc mySource.o -o mySource
```

You can add the `-ggdb` parameter to both lines if you plan on doing any debugging.

to add any library directories then on the link step append

```
-L<pathToLibrary>
```

to add any libraries then on the link step append, after any library parameters:

```
-l<shortLibName>
```

The initialization file for `vim` can contain the necessary info to invoke `gcc` by some keystroke combination, but I'm not totally familiar with the details.